# How can I insert records from a table to another table order by the specific column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know how can I insert records from a table to another table order by the specific column value?

For Example:

I have the following table:

**tableA:**

```
record_id int,
name varchar(100),
nickname(100),
chain_id int (PK),
chain_n int,
count int,
create_date datetime
```

**tableB:**

```
record_id int,
name varchar(100),
nickname(100),
chain_id int (PK),
chain_n int,
create_date datetime
```

I have the following value for tableA:

```
record_id      name      nickname      chain_id      chain_n      count      create_date
1              Test      One           1             1            2          2013-06-06
2              Test      Two           2             1            5          2013-06-06
3              Test      Three         3             1            3          2013-06-06
```

I using the following scrip to insert the data into thableB

```
INSERT INTO tableB
(
    record_id,
    name,
    nickname,
    chain_id,
    chain_n,
    create_date
)
SELECT 
(
    record_id,
    name,
    nickname,
    chain_id,
    chain_n,
    create_date
)
FROM tableA
ORDER BY count DESC
```

I expecting the data will insert into tableB like the following:

```
record_id      name      nickname      chain_id      chain_n      create_date
2              Test      Two           2             1            2013-06-06
3              Test      Three         3             1            2013-06-06
1              Test      One           1             1            2013-06-06
```

However, the result was as following still order by the chain_id

```
record_id      name      nickname      chain_id      chain_n      create_date
1              Test      One           1             1            2013-06-06
2              Test      Two           2             1            2013-06-06
3              Test      Three         3             1            2013-06-06
```

Does anyone know how can manage to insert the records order by the count instead

Comment: when you face any records from table without order by record will faced based on order by primary key because default cluster index key are set on primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that record_id is your primary key and thus default ordering is done by that. That's why your output is same as in tableA. Just use ORDER BY in SELECT clause for tableB.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting records into a table in particular order doesn't make much sense to me becuase ORDER BY doesn't actually influence the way the data is written to your drive. All records will be inserted in the order of your clustered index. In any case if you want to query data from a table ordered by some field you should explicitly state it in the ORDER BY clause even if you want your data ordered by clustered index columns. Although all data is meant to be ordered by clustered index by default it's still up to SQL Server engine to define the best execution plan and change the order if required if you don't specify it explicitly in the ORDER BY clause.